# Data about the safety of Da Vinci Robotic Surgery

Tags: openfda, medical

I am looking for data about the safety of the Da Vinci Robot.

- Have there been recalls on the Da Vinci Robot for not functioning properly?
- Have patients experienced terrible results via the use of the Da Vinci Robot and have they had to have other operations to correct mistakes made by the Da Vinci Robot?

Comment: What kind of data format are you looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the right place for such questions. This forum is for asking questions about how to program and work with the openFDA API.

Answer (score 1):

Jerry,

While I am not comfortable offering advice on the saftey of a device I will offer a method in which you can do your own research leveraging the OpenFDA API. Here is a search of medical device recalls for the term "Da Vinci" - http://www.researchae.com/recalls?reporttype=device&from_date=2004-01-01&to_date=2014-11-30&search=Da+Vinci